# Почему при переопределении Equals советуют также переопределять GetHashCode

Tags: c#, .net, c#-faq

Почему при переопределении метода `Equals()` также советуют переопределять метод`GetHashCode()`?
И еще один вытекающий вопрос:
Имея следующие поля

```
public readonly int x, y;
```

На [msdn.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173147(v=vs.90).aspx) метод `GetHashCode()` переопределяют следующим образом:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return x ^ y;
}
```

А если бы поля выглядели бы таким образом:

```
public readonly int x, y, z;
```

То переопределенный метод должен будет выглядеть так?

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return x ^ y ^ z;
}
```

Правильно я понял?
А что если тип данных у полей будет разным?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Дело в том, что любой объект в .NET можно положить в хеш-таблицу.

Допустим теперь, что у вас есть класс `X`, в котором переопределён метод `Equals`, но не переопределён `GetHashCode`. Что будет в этом случае?

Пусть у вас есть два объекта `x1` и `x2` типа `X`, которые совпадают согласно функции `Equals`. Поскольку вы не переопределили `GetHashCode`, то скорее всего их хэшкоды будут *разными*.

Если вы положите в `HashSet<X>` значение `x1`, а потом будете искать там `x2`, то при этом это значение **не будет найдено**, несмотря на то, что `x1` и `x2` у вас равны. Это произойдёт потому, что при поиске в `HashSet<X>` сначала ищется hash bucket, соответствующий хэшкоду, и лишь в нём ищется сам элемент — это базовый принцип работы хэш-таблицы, обеспечивающий её эффективность. Таким образом, элементы класса `X` нельзя будет нормально хранить в хэш-таблицах.

То же относится и к `Dictionary<X, T>`, который точно так же основан на хэш-таблице и пользуется методом `GetHashCode`.

---

По поводу правильного определения `GetHashCode`, совет с MSDN не очень хорош. Дело в том, что если у объекта есть два поля, то часто это маленькие числа, которые также часто бывают равны. Поэтому при таком определении будет слишком мало различных значений хэшкода, и много экземпляров `X` будут попадать в тот же самый hash bucket (что снижает эффективность хэш-таблиц).

Рекомендованный метод, судя по всему, такой (обновлено в 2023):

```
public override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(x, y);
```

(подсмотрено [здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode), будет работать не только для целочисленных полей) или, более изящно,

```
public override int GetHashCode() => (x, y).GetHashCode();
```

(подсмотрено [здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type), в текущей реализации «под капотом» всё равно будет вызван метод `HashCode.Combine`).

Для старых версий .NET, где не было удобного метода `HashCode.Combine`, можно комбинировать хэшкоды вручную:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    var hash = 19;
    // избегаем хэш-коллизий, используем (небольшое) простое число
    hash = hash * 37 + x.GetHashCode();
    hash = hash * 37 + y.GetHashCode();
    // обобщается на произвольное число полей
    return hash;
}
```

(19 и 37 — небольшие разные простые числа) Здесь типы полей неважны, т. к. на каждом из них берётся хэшкод.

Чего делать не стоит, так это использовать для хэшкода тяжеловесные методы наподобие вызова MD5: вычисление хэшкода для объектов в хэш-таблице может вызываться очень часто, и поэтому обязано быть быстрым.

Обязательно придерживайтесь правила: если объекты равны по `Equals`, у них **обязаны** быть одинаковые хэшкоды.

---

Ещё одно важное замечание: если вы кладёте в `HashSet<T>` элемент, вы не должны менять его состояние (значения полей) таким образом, чтобы его хэшкод изменился! Лучше всего, разумеется, вовсе не менять его. Иначе при поиске этого элемента он просто не будет найден.

---

Дополнительное чтение по теме:

- [Хешкод, переопределение метода GetHashCode](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/402923/10105)
- [What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/276994)
- [Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/371348/276994)
- Eric Lippert: [Guidelines and rules for GetHashCode](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/) (перевод на русский: [Правила и рекомендации по переопределению GetHashCode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ruericlippert/2011/03/20/943/))
- [Обзор альтернативных методов хэширования](https://archive.vn/KJeJy)

Comment: "Guidelines and rules for GetHashCode" - [перевод](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ruericlippert/2011/03/20/943/)

Comment: @MaLS: Спасибо! Включу в ответ.