# Переопределение GetHashCode

Tags: c#, .net

Троелсен в своей книге, советует переопределить метод `ToString()` у класса(переопределенная версия возвращает строку из полей всего класса через пробел), а потом в методе `GetHashCode` вызывать `this.ToString().GetHashCode()`.

Где-то читал критику такой реализации, например, вызов ToString() будет порождать мусор.

Правда ли, что она не очень хороша.

Какие могут быть альтернативы?

Comment: `GetHashCode(){return GetRuStackOverflow();}`.

Comment: @Other, не понял, что Вы имели ввиду?

Comment: @Umed, раньше был сайт `HashCode`, который стал `RuStackOverflow`. Ирония :)

Comment: @Other, очень тонко :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проблема со строкой состоит в том, что `GetHashCode()` может вызываться *очень часто*, много тысяч раз в секунду. Например, при поиске элемента в `HashSet<T>` или поиске ключа в `Dictionary<K, V>` у каждого искомого элемента берётся хэшкод. Если при этом будет каждый раз создаваться временная, никому за пределами метода не нужная строка, их потом должен будет очистить сборщик мусора.

Поэтому функция `GetHashCode` должна быть по возможности быстрой и не создавать дополнительных объектов.

По поводу того, как же лучше считать хэшкод, я бы посоветовал немного переделанный код из ответа @Umed:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 23 + field1.GetHashCode(); // для поля типа-значения, например int
        hash = hash * 23 + field2.GetHashCode(); // то же самое
        if (field3 != null)                      // а это для поля ссылочного типа
            hash = hash * 23 + field3.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Вместо 17 и 23 можно взять другие разные простые числа.

---

Ещё по теме: [Почему при переопределении Equals советуют также переопределять GetHashCode](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584376/10105).

Comment: да, Ваш вариант будет более понятным, нежели мой))

Comment: Умножение на 23 это что бы однозначно идентифицировать класс среди других типов?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Нет, это скорее чтобы хэшкоды лучше перемешивались. Если просто складывать хэшкоды, например, то `Point(1, 0)` и `Point(0, 1)` будут иметь одинаковые коды. А это плохо, хэшкоды должны быть по возможности разные.

Comment: @VladD вот только при таком подходе - подсчете хэшкода по всем полям - теряется сам смысл GetHashCode в качестве быстрой предпроверки Equals. Потому что для того же Point гораздо проще и быстрее сравнить сами объекты, чем высчитать хитрый хэшкод с арифметическими действиями. Т.е. return x.GetHashCode() может быть эффективнее,  чем магия с простыми числами.

Comment: @PashaPash: Ну да, гайдлайны вроде бы даже явно предостерегают от использования `GetHashCode` для предпроверки равенства. А `x.GetHadhCode()` ухудшает распределение в хэш-таблице.

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант, можно посчитать его как сумму хэшей его полей:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int result;
    uncheked
    {
        // если поле ссылочного типа,
        // то необходима проверка на null
        // если field1 будет null, то подставится 0
        result = this.field1?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
        result += this.field2?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
        //...
        result += this.fieldN.GetHashCode();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Либо через создание анонимного класса ([подсмотрел в английской SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4630550/4278250)):

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return new { this.field1, this.field2, /*... ,*/ this.fieldN }.GetHashCode();
}
```

Такой вариант тоже работает достаточно быстро, но за тем исключением, что каждый вызов порождает анонимный класс.

Там же можно посмотреть [ответ Джона Скита](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/4278250). Он накидал алгоритм с выбором двух случайных констант (они не меняются, случайных - потому что Вам надо их придумать один раз) и подсчёта хэша следующим образом:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 17;
        // если поле ссылочного типа,
        // то необходима проверка на null
        hash = hash * 23 + field1?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;

        // если это, например, int, то проверка ни к чему
        hash = hash * 23 + field3.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

*Добавил от себя проверку на null, о которой он там пишет в ответе*

Советую перейти по ссылке и посмотреть, там много полезного написано.

Comment: Ну, вариант с анонимным классом тоже создаёт объект в куче, то есть нагружает сборщик мусора, как и вариант со строкой.

Comment: @VladD, увы, это его минус, но знать о нём полезно, думаю. Но также привёл свой примитивный вариант и вариант который предложил Джон. :)

Comment: У меня ваш последний пример не компилируется :-(

Comment: @VladD, исправил, не учёл что для ссылочных типов `?.` вернёт не ноль, а `null`