# Как проверить, содержит ли поле хотя бы одна структура из List, пользуясь методом Contains ()?

Tags: c#, list, equals

Вкратце, нужно делать проверки у `List` методом `Contains()`, но сравнивать поле с полем структуры.

Пример кода:

```
struct Example
{
    string name;
    int ID;
    float parameter1;
    bool parameter2;
    
    Example(name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

List<Example> examples = new Example();
examples.Add(new Example("part1"));
examples.Add(new Example("part2"))

if (examples.Contains(string "part1"))
{
    // do something
}
```

Я пробовал переопределить метод `Equals()` в структуре таким образом и ничего у меня не вышло:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
   if(obj is string str) 
   return this.name == str;
}
public Equals(string str)
{
   return this.name == str;
}
```

Также есть вопрос заодно, почему надо переопределять метод `GetHashCode()` вместе с `Equals()`? Можно ли этот момент пропустить и будут ли последствия?

Comment: `if (examples.Any(z=>z.name == "abcde")) {}`?

Comment: `почему надо переопределять метод GetHashCode() вместе с Equals()` чтобы ваша структура в словарях/хешсетах работала как надо, см [доку](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-equals-gethashcode-methods?view=vs-2022)

Comment: [Почему при переопределении Equals советуют также переопределять GetHashCode](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584376/179763)